# Change drag and drop from jquery-ui-sortable list to click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I've inherited an old 'career finder' project. The gist of it is to select several adjectives, and it outputs what 'career' would be best for the user. I'm in the process of trying to make this mobile-friendly. It is using JQuery-Ui-Sortable, something I'm not too familiar with yet. For now, I'd like to change it so that I can simply click on one of the adjectives in the list, and it lands in the "sortable" ul (list). Currently, it only works when the user drags/drops list items. I know this is a long shot and apologize for any stupidity involved in the question, but I figured it was worth a try. It may be best to rebuild this from scratch in the end. Here is the related code:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap-careerFinder">
    <div class="programfinder">
            <div id="displaycharacter">
                <a id="programLink"><img height="725" width="740" alt="" id="career" style="border: 0px solid currentColor;" src="images/program-images/IT.jpg" /></a>
            </div>

            <ul class="sortablelist" id="list1">
                <li>Analytical</li>
                <li>Assertive</li>
                <li>Compassionate</li>
                <li>Confident</li>
                <li>Creative</li>
                <li>Detail Oriented</li>
                <li>Enjoys Challenges</li>
                <li>Flexible</li>
                <li>Communicator</li>
                <li>Good Listener</li>
                <li>Hard Worker</li>
                <li>Independent</li>
                <li>Likes to Learn</li>
                <li>Logical</li>
                <li>Multi-Tasker</li>
                <li>Observant</li>
                <li>Outgoing</li>
                <li>Passionate</li>
                <li>Patient</li>
                <li>Persistent</li>
                <li>Personable</li>
                <li>Problem Solver</li>
                <li>Professional</li>
                <li>Quick Reactor</li>
                <li>Visual Thinker</li>
                <li>Team Player</li>
                <li>Thick-Skinned</li>
                <li>Time Manager</li>
                <li>Trustworthy</li>
                <li>Self-Motivated</li>
                <li>Stress Manager</li>
                <li>Good Writer</li>
                <li>Resourceful</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="sortablelist-wrapper">
            <h4>How to Use the Career Finder</h4>
                <ul>
               <li><ul class="sortablelist" id="sortable"></ul><li>
               <li>
               <p>To help you find a career program that bests fits you, choose <b>6 characteristics</b> from the list on the left and drag them to the <b>My Characteristics</b> box. Click submit, below.</p>
               </li>
                </ul>
                   <div class="clear"></div>
                <button disabled="disabled" id="submitbtn" onclick="listAttr()" type="button"></button>

            </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
              <a href="index-home.html">Play Again</a>
        </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
var maxitems = 2;

var courses = [
//key : value, key : value
{"name":"Criminal Justice", "attrs": ["Multi-Tasker", "Assertive", "Team Player", "Confident", "Analytical", "Flexible Personality", "Patient", "Observant", "Trustworthy", "Thick-Skinned", "Stress Manager", "Quick Reactor"], "img" : "images/program-images/criminal-justice.jpg", "url" : "criminal-justice.html"},

{"name":"Accounting", "attrs": ["Detail Oriented", "Team Player", "Analytical", "Problem Solver", "Patient", "Resourceful", "Quick Reactor", "Enjoys Challenges", "Logical ", "Likes to learn", "Persistent"], "img" : "images/program-images/accounting.jpg", "url" : "accounting.html"},

{"name":"Business", "attrs": [ "Team Player", "Analytical", "Communicator", "Creative", "Flexible", "Passionate", "Patient", "Thick-Skinned", "Resourceful", "Persistent", "Stress Manager" ], "img" : "images/program-images/business.jpg", "url" : "business.html"},

{"name":"Health Fitness", "attrs": ["Confident", "Outgoing", "Passionate", "Good Listener", "Patient", "Compassionate", "Independent", "Self-Motivated", "Time Manager", "Resourceful", "Enjoys Challenges"], "img" : "images/program-images/health-fitness.jpg", "url" : "health-fitness.html"},

{"name":"IT", "attrs": ["Detail Oriented", "Team Player", "Analytical", "Problem Solver", "Patient", "Resourceful", "Quick Reactor", "Enjoys Challenges", "Logical", "Likes to Learn", "Persistent"], "img" : "images/program-images/IT.jpg", "url" : "information-tech.html"},

{"name":"Massage Therapy", "attrs": ["Confident", "Communicator", "Personable", "Flexible", "Visual Thinker", "Good Listener", "Compassionate", "Observant", "Independent", "Time Manager", "Self-Motivated", "Likes to Learn"], "img" : "images/program-images/massage-therapy.jpg", "url" : "massage-therapy.html"},

{"name":"Media Business", "attrs": ["Detail Oriented", "Confident", "Problem Solver", "Organized", "Communicator", "Creative", "Visual Thinker", "Passionate", "Good Listener", "Time Manager", "Logical", "Likes to Learn"], "img" : "images/program-images/engineer.jpg", "url" : "engineer.html"},

{"name":"Medical Assistant", "attrs": ["Team Player", "Communicator", "Personable", "Writing Skills", "Flexible", "Good Listener", "Compassionate", "Observant", "Trustworthy", "Stress Manager", "Quick Reactor", "Likes to Learn"], "img" : "images/program-images/medical-assistant.jpg", "url" : "medical-assistant.html"},

{"name":"Parelegal", "attrs": ["Multi-Tasker", "Detail Oriented", "Analytical", "Organized", "Good Writer", "Good Listener", "Hard Working", "Trustworthy", "Time Manager", "Professional", "Resourceful", "Logical"], "img" : "images/program-images/paralegal.jpg", "url" : "paralegal.html"},

{"name":"Vet-Tech", "attrs": ["Multi-Tasker", "Detail Oriented", "Team Player", "Organized", "Outgoing", "Compassionate", "Hard Working", "Observant", "Thick-Skinned", "Self-Motivated", "Quick Reactor", "Likes to Learn"], "img" : "images/program-images/vet-tech.jpg", "url" : "vet-tech.html"},

{"name":"Internet Marketing", "attrs": ["Multi-Tasker", "Likes to Learn", "Creative", "Flexible", "Problem Solver", "Good Writer", "Resourceful", "Observant", "Enjoys Challenges", "Time Manager", "Analytics", "Self-Motivated"], "img" : "images/program-images/architecture.jpg", "url" : "architecture.html"},

{"name":"Architecture", "attrs": ["Detail Oriented", "Confident", "Problem Solver", "Qrganized", "Visual Thinker", "Passionate", "Good Listener", "Time Management", "Logical", "Likes to Learn"], "img" : "images/program-images/media.jpg", "url" : "internet-marketing.html"},

{"name":"Nursing", "attrs": ["Multi-Tasker", "Problem Solver", "Personable", "Good Listener", "Patient", "Compassionate", "Observant", "Thick-Skinned", "Stress Manager", "Quick Reactor", "Logical"], "img" : "images/program-images/nursing.jpg", "url" : "nursing.html"},

{"name":"Health Care Management", "attrs": ["Multi-Tasker", "Detail Oriented", "Assertive", "Confident", "Problem Solver", "Good Communicator", "Writing Skills", "Flexible", "Compassionate", "Logical", "Good Communicator"], "img" : "images/program-images/healthcare-management.jpg", "url" : "healthcare-managment.html"}
//each section is a key 0 to max#... array inside of a array with value


$(function() {
    $( "#list1, #sortable" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".sortablelist",
        change:dropin

    }).disableSelection();
});
function dropin(event, ui){
    //this is where you total amt to drag into selected area
    if ($("#sortable li").length == maxitems +4){
        $( "#list1, #sortable" ).sortable({ disabled: true });
        $("#submitbtn").removeAttr("disabled");  

    }

}

function listAttr (){
    //bestmatch will equal courses
    var bestmatch;
    //matches equal attrs and li items
    var matches = 0;
    //loop through each course
    $(courses).each(function(key, value){
        var attrs = value.attrs;
        var counter = 0;
        //loop each chosen attr
        $("#sortable li").each(function(){
            var traits = $(this).text();
            //loop through all attr of this course
            $(attrs).each (function (i, val){
            //if it matches will add to the counter 
                if (traits == val){
                    counter ++;
                    }
            });
        }); 
        //compare to the top match and see if its more or less
        if (counter > matches) {
        //if larger then set as best match by this point counter equals total li matches
                bestmatch = value;  
                matches = counter;  
        }

    });
    //id from the images pulling from json name to img pathway
    $("#career").attr("src", bestmatch.img).show();
    $("#programLink").attr("href", bestmatch.url);


}
```

So is there any chance this could easily be changed to include clicking instead of just dragging and dropping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isnt part of sortable. However you could add a click listener to all the elements in list1 and set it to detach the item add add it to the sortable list

Something like

```
$('#list1 li').click(function(event){
    $(event.target).closest('li').detach().appendTo('#sortable');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Couldn't figure that bit out for the life of me. This definitely gets me 90% there! My "submit" button stopped working, but the click event IS working, and that's what I was going for. Cheers.